# Creating webhook for Stripe in Node Express application; issue reading request

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm unable to read the request coming from Stripe or even to log a test string when the endpoint is hit.

Stripe says that the test was successful, but I'm unable to take action on the request.

Here's what my app.js file contains.

```js
var billingWebhook = require('./routes/billingWebhook');
// Additional code here
app.use('/billingWebhook', billingWebhook);
```

Here's what my routes/billingWebhook.js file contains.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  console.log("We got here");
  let event;
  try {
    event = JSON.parse(request.body);
  }
  catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
      break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
      const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
      handlePaymentMethodAttached(paymentMethod);
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      return response.status(400).end();
  }

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.json({received: true});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Below is the URL that the webhook is set up for:
`https://xxxx.ngrok.io/billingWebhook/webhook`

Here's what the terminal reads:
[image]

Here's what Stripe reads:
[image]

Comment: Have you defined `handlePaymentIntentSucceeded` and `handlePaymentMethodAttached` anywhere? Otherwise you'll get an error before your server can return the status to Stripe.